# String concatenation, why does this compile?

Tags: c++

I found this in my code, was a typo on my part, but it still compiled. Anyone know why?
I have no idea.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string x;
  std::string b = "Bryan";
  x += '|' + b, x;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Awesome help guys, thanks alot for clearing this up for me

Comment: Side Note: If you compile with warnings `g++ -Wall` produces `warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]`

Comment: You should get a compiler warning, if you've enabled warnings. The compiler can spot that `, x` does nothing, meaning that it's probably a mistake.

Comment: ok, im going to enable warnings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
x += '|' + b, x;
```

Here `,` is basically an operator whose left operand is evaluated first, followed by right operand. It is that simple.

Since the precedence of `+=` and `+` is higher than `,` operator, it becomes equivalent to this:

```
(x += '|' + b) ,  x;
```

Here:

```
left  operand => (x += '|' + b)
right operand =>  x
```

Try another example:

```
int f() { ... }
int g() { ... }

f(), g();
```

Here `f()` will be called first followed by `g()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why is `+=` treated differently than `=` here?

Comment: @mohit: I don't know what you mean by "differently". Still I guess you want to know this : `+=` and `=` have same precedence. It is just that `,` has lower precedence than both of them!

Comment: Got it. I was under wrong impression that `a = 4, 5;` would set `a` to `5`. Thanks.

Comment: @mohit: No, `a=4,5` would set `a` to `4`. If you want it to be `5`, then write `a=(4,5)` or simply `a=5`.

Comment: Is there any legitimate reason to do this? What's the purpose of this operator?

Answer (score 3):

```
x += '|' + b, x;
```

This compiles because the comma here is acting as an operator (instead of a separator) where the right-hand operand has no effect.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).
>
> ...
>
> The comma operator has the lowest precedence of any C operator...

In `x += '|' + b, x;`, operator `+=` has a higher precedence than `,` and operator `+` has a higher precedence than `+=`, meaning that it's equivalent to `(x += ('|' + b)), x`;

Additionally, if you compile your code with warnings on, you will likely receive a warning similar to this:

```
warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x += '|' + b, x;
```

This is a comma operator, which has the lowest precedence. It takes two operands, , evaluates them left to right. Both of its operands are perfectly legal in this example:

Note that comma operator has a value of the right operand, but it's usually useless, like in this example. So it's the same with:

```
x += '|' + b;
x;  // no effect
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x += '|' + b, x;
```

It's because the the expression before the `,` operator takes to effect. For example -

```
std::string y("Hello");
x += '|' + b, y;
```

The above would still give the result `|Bryan` in your program.